# Problems using USB-ASP

Tags: code, microcontroller

I am trying to upload some code to my MCU *ATMega 32a* using an USB-ASP programmer and extreme burner software.

I am just using some dummy code, but everytime I try to burn it, the extreme burner shows the following error

[image: extreme burner error]

Can anyone help me?
I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Extreme Burner may not support ATmega 32A (low power).
Give a try to recent [AVRDUDE](http://download.savannah.gnu.org/releases/avrdude/) (>= 5.2 for USBASP support)